# How to get the second best value

Tags: sql, ms-access

Assume we have two tables:

```
Players(player_id int)
GameScores(player_id int, session_id int, score int)
```

How can we query the second highest-score session for every player?

For example if

```
Players
1
2

GameScores
(player_id, session_id, score)
1 1 10
1 2 20 
1 3 40
2 4 10
2 5 20

Then result would be
(player_id, session_id)
1, 2
2, 4
```

Comment: does the GameScores table have a Primary Key? what is its name?

Comment: @LuisSiquot yes, it's session_id.

Comment: well, if there are two records that have the same 1st score, what has to do the query: A) discard both, B)Take one of them as 2nd ???

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this

```
     SELECT GameScores.player_id, GameScores.session_id 
     FROM (
        SELECT player_id,MAX(score) as SecondScore
        FROM GameScores g
        WHERE score < (SELECT Max(Score) FROM gameScore where gameScore.player_id = g.player_id)
        GROUP BY player_id 
        ) x
        INNER JOIN GameScores ON x.player_id = gamescore.player_id 
          AND x.SecondScore = gamescore.score
```

---

This is the query that select the second high score for each player

```
SELECT player_id,MAX(score) as SecondScore
            FROM GameScores g
            WHERE score < (SELECT Max(Score) FROM gameScore where gameScore.player_id = g.player_id)
            GROUP BY player_id
```

You can't group by session in this query. So that's why you need to put this in a subquery and join it to `gamescore` to get the `session_id`

Comment: You might get a circular reference error by aliasing `MAX(Score) as Score` - at least I did in Access 2010 when testing your query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snippet for Oracle sql

```
select tbl.player_id,tbl.session_id from
(select p.player_id,g.session_id,g.score,rank()  over (partition by p.player_id order by score desc) rnk   from players p,
gamescores g 
where p.player_id = g.player_id) tbl
where tbl.rnk = 2;
```

Comment: do not exists `over` and related in ms-access

Answer (score 0):

```
select player_id, first(session_id) as session_id
from 
   GameScores inner join (
   select player_id, max(score) as secondscore
   from 
      GameScores left join (
      select player_id, max(score) as firstscore
      from GameScores
      group by player_id
   ) as NotThisOnes on GameScores.player_id = NotThisOnes.player_id
                   and GameScores.score = NotThisOnes.firstscore
   where NotThisOnes.player_id is null
   group by player_id
) as thisare on GameScores.player_id = thisare.player_id
            and GameScores.score     = thisare.secondscore
group by player_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach... I am not sure if this is better than other answers, but i wanted to solve it this way:

```
SELECT
  GameScores.player_id,
  GameScores.session_id,
  GameScores.score
FROM
  GameScores
WHERE
  GameScores.score=
    (select max(score) from GameScores GameScores_2
     where GameScores.player_id = GameScores_2.Player_ID
     and GameScores_2.Score<
       (select max(score) from GameScores GameScores_1
        where GameScores_1.player_id = GameScores.player_id));
```